# Multi-threaded bruteforce algorithm

Tags: c, multithreading, algorithm, brute-force

I have a multi-threaded program which bruteforces a password by incrementing a string, taking chars delimited by a string.

I thought I could slice the *"dictionnary"* (set of chars) between threads but I'm obviously wrong.

What I'm doing is splitting the *dictionnary* into as many pieces as there are threads, and then let them work on their subset of chars.

Here is my *dictionnary* :

```
static const char tab[] =
"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
"ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
"0123456789"
"!*~";
```

So basically I'm doing something stupid, since if I split it between 4 threads, one will be able to test i.e. "adef" but never "a*1b".

So I guess there's a much better solution, however I can't really wrap my head around it.

Here is my incrementing algorithm (There's more to it, but I'm putting only what's important):

```
void *func(void * bound){

 char Test[5]="0000";

 int u = bound + nb_pas;
 for (int h = bound; h <= u; ++h){
    Test[3] = tab[h];
    for (int k = bound; k <= u; ++k){
        Test[2] = tab[k];
        for (int j = bound; j <= u; ++j){
            Test[1] = tab[j];
            for (int i = bound; i <= u; ++i){
                Test[0] = tab[i];
                if(finished == 1){
                    for(int r = 1 ; r < nb_thread; r++ ){                            
                        pthread_cancel(tid[r]);                            
                    }
                    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
                }

                char *hash = crypt_r(Test,salt,cdata);

                if(strcmp(hash,ciphertext) == 0 ){


                    // Impression du résultat
                    printf("Password found: %s\n", Test);
                    printf("Hashed version of password is %s\n", hash);
                    printf("It took %f seconds to complete in %i steps \n", elapsed, compteur);
                    finished = 1;
                    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
                }

            }
        }
    }
}

if (finished == 0){
    printf(" NO MATCH\n");
}
 return 0;
}
```

Where `bound` is an `int` passed to the thread corresponding to `(# of chars / # of threads) * thread index` and `nb_pas` is `(# of chars / # of threads)`

How should I approach this ? I thought about simulating the incrementing with loops before assigning the function to threads, but I'm not sure how to do it...

Thanks for your help

**Edit**

Here is how I spawn threads

```
for(int i = 0; i < nb_thread; i++){
        int b = nb_pas*i;
        if (pthread_create(&tid[i],NULL,func, b)!=0){ 
            printf("Une erreur s'est produite");
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }

    }
```

Comment: All threads must use the same dictionary, but the first letter of the password can be different. Fix just the first letter of a password to the thread.

Comment: you can divide the work however you like, but the way that I would divide it up would be: the top loop would use the `index mod numberOfThreads` to see if it should evaluate all of the sub loops... you do all of the sub loops

Comment: @GradyPlayer I'm not sure what you mean, basically if `h % nb_threads == 0`, then I should `continue` ? What would differentiate the work of different threads then ? Could you be so kind to explain a bit further ? Thx

Comment: each thread would be either 0, 1, 2, or 3, and just service 1/4 or requests for 4... you have to give each thread a serial number, or figure out a way to derive a unique series of numbers... you don't have to worry specifically about "thread local storage" because your stack variables are stack local.

Answer (score 0):

You may try something like

```
for (i=0; i<nbthread; i++) {
    pthread_create(......,func,i*strlen(tab)/nbthread);
}
```

then :

```
func(void *bound) {
    int start = (int)bound;
    int end = start+strlen(tab)/nbthread;
    for (i=start; i<end];i++) { // just one slice of the alphabet
       Test[0] = tab[i];
       for(j=0; j<strlen(tab); j++) { // every letter
           Test[1] = tab[j];
              ....

}
```

Comment: I edited to add more of my code. Test is local to the thread, isn't it ? Thanks for your help, what do you mean by _the description of the slice_ ?

Comment: With more of your code I can say : yes `Test` is local to your threads, and `bound` is (in some way) the description of the slice (the starting point of a slice for you). It seems that you've made mistakes. Divide your space into slices first [a????-c????] second [d????-f????], etc. And limit the first loop to [a-c] for the first slice, [d-f] for the second, etc. Every other loop should loop through every possible values...